# Data loading is slow while using "Insert/Update" step in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, data-integration

Data loading is slow while using "Insert/Update" step in pentaho 4.4.0

I am using pentaho 4.4.0. While using the "Insert/Update" step in kettle the speed of the data load is too slow compared to mysql. This step will scan through the entire records in table before inserting. If the record exist it will do a update. So what shall be done to optimize the performance while doing "Insert/Update" . and the process speed is 4 r/s, so totally my records will be above 1 lakh... The process takes 2 and half hours to complete the entire process.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments it sounds like you want the `Merge rows (diff)` step followed by a `Synchronize after merge`. Check the [Pentaho wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pentaho+Data+Integration+Steps) to see how these steps work.

Another thing that makes a big difference is how many of the rows result in an upsert vs how many total rows. If the number of rows resulting in writes is more than roughly 40%, @carexcer's last comment may be a better approach. If it's less, definitely try the `Merge rows (diff)` step.

4 - 25 rows per second sounds way slow. Be sure the fields you marked as keys are indexed, whichever step you choose.

If most of the rows result in an upsert, you may be better off with a full refresh. If that's the case, check out the MySQL bulk loaders. Pentaho has both a batch and streaming bulk loader, though I don't know how good they are.

Comment: Thank you sir, I used merge rows(diff) step followed by a Synchronize after merge... so, now my process executed 1 minute for 111744 records... but when i used insert/update i took 2 hours for 111744 records...

Comment: Great news! I tend not to use the `Insert/Update` for exactly that reason. `Merge rows (diff)` is usually way faster. If that's what worked for you, can you mark my answer as accepted? Thanx.

Comment: Thanks I used it and it much faster, but how insert/update step is difference from the merge/synchronize step why it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a big value on the field *Transaction Size (Commit)*.

Depending on the number of rows you will upsert, set more or less on that field.

This improve so much the performance in my case.

500 would be a little value if you will upsert, in example, 100.000 rows, because it will have to be commited 200 times.

Less commits, faster execution.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply..if i used the commit size is 500 then the speed is same as before.. so can i do....

Comment: How many rows are you loading? If 500 is too slow, try to set a bigger value (10.000, 20.000, 50.000, 100.000... depending on the number of rows you are upserting). Another question... it's necessary for you to use the "Insert/Update" step? I had the same problem in the past when I was loading a fact table on a datawarehouse, and in my case the "Output Table" step was very faster than "Insert/update" step. Remember that less commits, faster execution.

Comment: Yes.. I want only Insert/Update..  my requirement is If the row can't be found, it inserts the row. If it can be found and the fields to update are the same, nothing is done. If they are not all the same, the row in the table is updated.

Comment: If i use the commit size is 100000 then the starting speed my process id 25 r/s but the speed is reducing while new records are inserting.. so at the end process the speed is 4 r/s....

Comment: I think you have a bottleneck on your process. Can you give more information about what are you doing? (Snapshot of process for example). I guess you are loading a datawarehouse dimension or fact.

Comment: for small number records its executed fastly but for long records only its executing too slow...

Comment: How many records are "long records"? 1.000.000? 100.000.000? Maybe you could try another way. Try to do a Lookup of the datawarehouse table you want to upsert and for insertions use "Output table" with a very big "Transaction Size Commit". The most time is probably used by updates, so if you could run in parallel the insertions and updates you will reduce the execution time. I can't help you more without knowing the particular situation.

Comment: I have a text file that I need to load into a database... I used merge rows(diff)... I compared the text file input with table input step.. i used sorted merge for sorting columns for both text file input and table input steps.. and i used merge rows(diff) step followed by Synchronize after merge... My problem is if i run my job first time its inserting the text file data to database.. and the second time also its inserting same rows again into the database... Can any one please help me what mistake i did..

Answer (score 1):

**useServerPrepStmts - false**

**useCursorFetch     - true**

**useCompression     - true**

You can try editing the Connection and put these parameters there.
This will increase the performance.

Double Click on the Database Connection -> Options tab -> Add above parameters.

Answer (score 0):

With mysql all other options dont work well
I have try with some cheat

```
Insert into A(a,b) values (1,2);
Insert into A(a,b) values (2,2);
Insert into A(a,b) values (3,2);
```

Change to

```
Insert into A(a,b) values (1,2), (2,2), (3,2);
```

I'ts perfect way