# SQL Server - Insert too slow into table

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-performance, pentaho-data-integration

My table have 47 columns without data,
No index, no triger, no constraints, no foreign keys.
Just simple.
But speed insert is ~50 row/s. Too slow!
I have tried many times in different times

Please help me how to check and find really problem in my case.
Thanks bros!

Comment: The problem is not sql server. How do you insert these rows?

Comment: Data has loaded from file into table by pentaho kettel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969624/data-loading-is-slow-while-using-insert-update-step-in-pentaho you're  not alone. Check the advice you find there.

Comment: Transaction? Bulk insert/BCP? TVP? What have you tried? What storage do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for support.
I was restart database and the problem has been resolved.